# asp:Calendar issue in apple safari support

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I am  using custom asp:Calendar control in my application.
I am opening my application through safari browser.
when I am trying select date calender pop up is displaying after selecting date it is not setting to calender textbox.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Arguably, it is considered one of the safest ways to avoid compatibility problems across different browsers.

Hope this helps.